# Running a python script getting Execution ID on output location

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am running a python script, but getting the execution ID as a .txt file in the output location. Is there a way where I can comment it and stop getting these ID's as an output. Below is the python script:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3
import datetime


# Function for executing athena queries

def run_ddl_query(ddl_query, database, s3_ddl_output):
    client = boto3.client('athena')
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': 's3_accesslog'
            },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': s3_ddl_output,
            }
        )
    print('Execution ID: ' + response['QueryExecutionId'])
    return response
    
def run_query(query, database, s3_output):
    client = boto3.client('athena')
    
    # Setup and perform query
    response = client.start_query_execution(
            QueryString=query,
            QueryExecutionContext={
                 'Database': database
            },
            ResultConfiguration={
                 'OutputLocation': s3_output,
            }
        )

# Athena configuration
s3_ouput = 's3://xxxxx/athenatest/'
database = 's3_accesslog'
table = 'test_output'

# import datetime
year = datetime.date.today()
year = year.strftime('%Y')
month = datetime.date.today()
month = month.strftime('%m')
day = datetime.date.today()
day = day.strftime('%d')

# select bucket

s3_input = 's3://xxxxx/cf-ant-prod/cf-mon-prod/year=%s/month=%s/day=%s' % (year, month, day)

#Athena database and table definition
create_database = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s;" % (database)
create_table = \
  """CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s.%s (
  `Date` DATE,
   Time STRING,
   Location STRING,
   SCBytes BIGINT,
   RequestIP STRING,
   Method STRING,
   Host STRING,
   Uri STRING,
   Status INT,
   Referrer STRING,
   UserAgent STRING,
   UriQS STRING,
   Cookie STRING,
   ResultType STRING,
   RequestId STRING,
   HostHeader STRING,
   Protocol STRING,
   CSBytes BIGINT,
   TimeTaken FLOAT,
   XForwardFor STRING,
   SSLProtocol STRING,
   SSLCipher STRING,
   ResponseResultType STRING,
   CSProtocolVersion STRING,
   FleStatus STRING,
   FleEncryptedFields INT,
   CPort INT,
   TimeToFirstByte FLOAT,
   XEdgeDetailedResult STRING,
   ScContent STRING,
   ScContentLen BIGINT,
   ScRangeStart BIGINT,
   ScRangeEnd BIGINT
   )
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
   LOCATION '%s'
   TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count' = '2');""" % ( database, table, s3_input )

#Query definitions
query_1 = "SELECT * FROM %s.%s where CAST(status AS VARCHAR) like '404';" % (database, table)

#Execute all queries
queries = [ create_database, create_table, query_1, ]
for q in queries:
   print("Executing query: %s" % (q))
   res = run_query(q, database, s3_ouput)
```

I tried commenting the print('Execution ID: ' + response['QueryExecutionId']), when I retry executing the script it doesn't show up, but I see the .txt files in the output path.

```
$ ./Athena_Script_new.py
Executing query: CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS xxxxxx;
Execution ID: 21c2e158-b774-473c-812a-7ff121a688a2
Executing query: drop table xxxxxx.xxxxxxx;
Execution ID: cd39087a-f18f-4d93-aa71-26c5402cdc7d
Executing query: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS xxxxxx.xxxxx (
  `Date` DATE,
   Time STRING,
   Location STRING,
   SCBytes BIGINT,
   RequestIP STRING,
   Method STRING,
   Host STRING,
   Uri STRING,
   Status INT,
   Referrer STRING,
   UserAgent STRING,
   UriQS STRING,
   Cookie STRING,
   ResultType STRING,
   RequestId STRING,
   HostHeader STRING,
   Protocol STRING,
   CSBytes BIGINT,
   TimeTaken FLOAT,
   XForwardFor STRING,
   SSLProtocol STRING,
   SSLCipher STRING,
   ResponseResultType STRING,
   CSProtocolVersion STRING,
   FleStatus STRING,
   FleEncryptedFields INT,
   CPort INT,
   TimeToFirstByte FLOAT,
   XEdgeDetailedResult STRING,
   ScContent STRING,
   ScContentLen BIGINT,
   ScRangeStart BIGINT,
   ScRangeEnd BIGINT
   )
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '  '
   LOCATION 's3://xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/year=2020/month=09/day=03'
   TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count' = '2');
Execution ID: d3ed413b-43ed-445e-92bd-e5ef794d2948
Executing query: SELECT * FROM xxxxxx.xxxxxxx where CAST(status AS VARCHAR) like '404';
Execution ID: be2378bd-c10e-4714-9611-978200cc8866
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Code responsible for putting your results is

```
ResultConfiguration={
  'OutputLocation': s3_output,
}
```

What files the response consists of seems to be hardcoded by AWS and can not be changed, see [AWS Athena, Working with Query Results, Output Files, and Query History](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html).

You may add removing this .txt file manually once it appears, but I wonder why you would need to remove this .txt and keep other parts of result. I think common usage was assumed to keep or use and delete whole answer (all objects in output location).

Comment: I'm looking only for the output from select query, but wherein there are many .txt files in it. I'm planning to execute this query on a daily basis, so I might see more of these txt files which is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

The .txt files are created by DDL statements that you are executing in your script. I see multiple DDL statements which are creating these text files. For each DDL there will be a .txt file generated in the configured `OutputLocation`. [Refer to Identifying Query Output Files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html) to know more about this.

You cannot prevent them from generating but you can simply let them generate in some other location or clean them by looking for .txt files in the `OutputLocation`.

I believe changing the location for these files to be generated is an easy option. All you need to do is create one more function as shown below. So when you want to run a DDL query use this function instead.

```
def run_ddl_query(ddl_query, database, s3_ddl_output):
    client = boto3.client('athena')
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': 's3_accesslog'
            },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': s3_ddl_output,
            }
        )
    print('Execution ID: ' + response['QueryExecutionId'])
    return response
```

So this will create .txt files in another location/folder in the same bucket which you can simply delete by using something like [`S3.Client.delete_object`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=delete#S3.Client.delete_object)

Comment: Thanks for the response Prabhakar, as said I have update the script now getting the below error:Executing query: CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS s3_accesslog;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Athena_Script.py", line 88, in <module>
    res = run_query(q, database, s3_ouput)
NameError: name 'run_query' is not defined

Comment: you have to create two functions.One for DDL and another for select queries. The function that I gave is additional to what you have in your script.

Comment: Can you please confirm the above script if this how you want me to execute and try?

Comment: add this function to your existing script and use this function only for DDL queries with different location

Comment: were you able to execute the query by creating two functions?